# JQUERY autocomplete not refreshing data from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using autocomplete to select some fields from my Mysql DB.
Everything works fine, the autocomplete is working ok.

The only thing is when I submit the form to the database I always have to refresh my page before I see the result fromt the update query.
The update is performed ok as it is changing the values in the database.
When I remove the autoupdate jquery script from my page it is working fine the value update without page refresh.

Here's the code of my jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tag").autocomplete( {
        source: 'autocomplete.php',
        minLength: 3,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#tag").val(ui.item.label);
            $('#PARTNER_ID').val(ui.item.value);            
        }
    });
});
```

I do the update query, and in Php I have this code after the sql update:

```
if($result2){
    header("location:contact_detail.php?ID=".$CONTACTS_ID);
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: the autocomplete works ok. But your update query has a flaw. So why are we only seeing the autocomplete code?? If the update code has a problem, maybe you need to post that code?

Comment: Hi the update query has no flaw, as mentioned above when removing the Jquery script from the page it works without a problem the DB is updated and I don't have to refresh my page to see the result. Adding the script back, the update in the DB is still working fine. But I only see the result on my page after I refresh it...

Comment: how is this other update happening? Is it another ajax call? I suggest that when the autocomplete is included (and/or after it has been used), you should look in your browser console to see if there are any errors or anything.